# How to store multiple images of picturebox in database?

Tags: c#

I have dynamic generated picturebox in my windows form app c#.which could have 3,4,5 or any nuber of picturebox(depends on user) now i want to save all this picture box images in database in single field! how??

Answer (score -1):

"...I want to save all this picture box images in database in **single field!**..."

Don't do it. You'll have a heck of a hard time recovering the individual images back.

Store each image in a separate table just for this purpose (since the actual number of images varies) and join to this table by a common key.

Storing the images in SQL Server is easy. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Usin) example.